# Why my JQuery custom data validation don't get executed on submit?

Tags: asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to figure out why my custom validation (i.e. the `IsEmailValid` method) is not getting executed when I press the "submit" (i.e. Share) button below. The `Required` one is getting executed fine but my custom validation attribute - `IsEmailAttribute` is not getting called. Can someone please provide some directions.

That is my **index.cshtml** where my form is rendered via `Html.RenderPartial`:

```
@using System.Security.Principal
@using DNAAnalysisCore.Resources
@model DNAAnalysisCore.ViewModels.WorkbookViewModel

@section BodyFill
    {
    <div id="shareFormContainer">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ShareView", new WorkbookShareModel());}
    </div>

    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var workbook in Model.Workbooks)
        {
            <tr class="@trClassName">
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(linkText, "Open", "OpenAnalytics", new { id = Model.Id, workbook = workbook.Name })</td>
                <td class="last-modified-date" title="Last Modified Date">@workbook.ModifiedDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                <td class="share">
                    <button title="Share" class="share-button" onclick='showSharingView("@workbook.Name", "@workbook.Id", "@Model.Id")'>&nbsp;</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@section Scripts
    {
    <!--Load JQuery 'unobtrusive' validation -->
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function showSharingView(title, workbookId, id) {            
            var isEmailAdapterName = 'isEmail';        
            $('#shareFormModal').modal("show");

            // client-side email validation
            $.validator.addMethod(isEmailAdapterName, IsEmailValid);
            // register the 'isEmail' attribute with the 'unobtrusive' validation
            $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(isEmailAdapterName,
                [],
                function(options) {
                    // add a 'isEmail' rule to the options so that JQuery can find it when it's checking the rules collection
                    options.rules.isEmail = {};
                    // add a message for the 'isEmail' rule ('message' will have the 'ShareModel' attribute 'ErrorMessage' value)
                    options.messages[isEmailAdapterName] = options.message;
                });
        }

        function hideDialog() {
            var form = $("#partialform");
            // only hide the dialog if the form is valid
            if (form.valid()) {
                $('#shareFormModal').modal("hide");
            }
        }

        // Helper method that validates list of emails
        function IsEmailValid(emailList, element, parameters) {
            // EMAIL VALIDATION LOGIC HERE
        }
    </script>
}
```

That is my Model:

```
public class WorkbookShareModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput] 
    public string WorkbookId { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.BaseLanguage), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Email_Requirement_Warning")]
    [IsEmailAttribute(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.BaseLanguage), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Email_Invalid_Message")]
    public IList<string> Emails { get; set; }
}

public class IsEmailAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var share = (WorkbookShareModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        foreach (var email in share.Emails)
        {
            var convertedEmail = email.Trim().ToLower();
            var match = Regex.Match(convertedEmail, Constants.EmailPattern);
            // if one of the emails does not match the pattern, break out of the look and return the error message
            if (!match.Success)
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-isEmail", errorMessage);
    }

    private void MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
    {
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
            return;

        attributes.Add(key, value);
    }
}
}
```

That is my form:

```
@using DNAAnalysisCore.Resources
@model DNAAnalysisCore.Models.WorkbookShareModel

<!-- Modal -->
<div onclick="activateShareButtons()" class="modal fade" id="shareFormModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 id="dialogDisplayTitle" class="modal-title">THIS VALUE IS SET VIA JAVASCRIPT</h4>
            </div>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("ShareWorkbook", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "partialform" }))
            {
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <label>@BaseLanguage.Share_workbook_Instruction_text</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="Emails" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="@BaseLanguage.ShareDialogPlaceholder"></textarea>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Emails" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <input asp-for="Title" />
                    <input asp-for="Id" />
                    <input asp-for="WorkbookId"/>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button onclick="hideDialog()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Share</button>
                    <button onclick="activateShareButtons()" id="btnCancelDialog" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            }

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI - the jQuery Validate plugin and the jQuery Validation Engine are not the same plugin.  In this case, everything has to do with how ASP controls validation via the Unobtrusive Validation plugin.  Edited tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by moving the `$.validator.addMethod` and `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add` method calls outside the `showSharingView` method. That worked and my custom error is shown properly. However, I am not sure why, though:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var isEmailAdapterName = 'isEmail';
    // client-side email validation
    $.validator.addMethod(isEmailAdapterName, IsEmailValid);
    // register the 'isEmail' attribute with the 'unobtrusive' validation
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(isEmailAdapterName,
        [],
        function(options) {
            // add a 'isEmail' rule to the options so that JQuery can find it when it's checking the rules collection
            options.rules[isEmailAdapterName] = {};
            // add a message for the 'isEmail' rule ('message' will have the 'ShareModel' attribute 'ErrorMessage' value)
            options.messages[isEmailAdapterName] = options.message;
        });

    function showSharingView(title, workbookId, id) {
        $('.share-button').prop('disabled', true); // Disable all share buttons to avoid opening multiple dialogs
        // reset the 'Emails' textarea 
        $('#Emails').val('');
        // set the dialog's control values
        $('#Title').val(title);
        $('#Id').val(id);
        $('#WorkbookId').val(workbookId);
        // set the dialog's title 
        $('#dialogDisplayTitle').html("Share Workbook - " + title);

        $('#shareFormModal').modal("show");
    }
```